# How to configure CouchDB to only accept JWTs with a specific aud (audience) claim?

Tags: couchdb

The title says it all, really. If you have a JWT from google, for example, it have an aud claim with the id of your app. Otherwise any site owner could use any JWT to log into any other site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configure this in required_claims, the [provided example](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/bfda16348f5c61e274ad5087e4a6407fa8306e0d/rel/overlay/etc/default.ini#L163) of a claim with a parameter is an `iss` claim:

```
;[jwt_auth]
; List of claims to validate
; can be the name of a claim like "exp" or a tuple if the claim requires
; a parameter
; required_claims = exp, {iss, "IssuerNameHere"}
```

but that could be changed to different claims, i.e.:

```
[jwt_auth]
required_claims = iat, exp, {aud, "my-project"}
```

Comment: Is there a way to allow different audiences?